# C++ program crashes before theApp::InitInstance()

Tags: visual-c++-2005

Visual C++ 2005 Professional
Debug/Win32
Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit

I set a breakpoint at my program's entrypoint.  My program crashes before reaching that breakpoint.  When the unhandled exception occurs (Access violation reading location 0x00000000.), I click on Break, and set a breakpoint where the current instruction pointer is located.  Restart the debugging session and the program stops on the new breakpoint.  I scroll up to the top of the current function, __tmainCRTStartup(), and set a breakpoint at the opening brace for the function.

I stop/restart the debugger again, this time stopping at __tmainCRTStartup().  By this time, all of the DLL's have been loaded, and if they needed to, run their load functions.  Press [F5] to run to the original breakpoint.  The Next Statement pointer is pointing at a call to WinMain(...).

Stepping over this statement causes the unhandled exception.  Stepping into the statement takes me to this statement: "return AfxWinMain(hInstance, hPrevInstance, lpCmdLine, nCmdShow);".  Stepping into once again takes me to the Disassembly window, where I see the next statement to run: "jmp         AfxWinMain (563AFAh)".

I can step through the assembly code, but I cannot make out what it is trying to do before it tries to dereference a pointer in one of the registers, which holds a value of zero (0).

I read another post about a C program crashing before reaching main().  Even though tagged with "C", many responders mentioned constructors of a static instance of a class being a possible culprit.  Others mentioned DLL's loading and running their own startup code that might crash the program, but the DLL's all seem to load and I have evidence of at least one DLL running its startup code, before the program gets to __tmainCRTSetup() .

Can anyone help me understand this?  Knowing why it's doing this should help me understand how to fix it.

Thank you!

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that the your class derived from  CWinApp is not declared globally.  Without seeing your code that's the only thing that jumps to mind.

Comment: Please read [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include as much relevant code and information you can. It's easier for people to help you that way.

Comment: From MyApp.h:

class CCPDATA73App : public CWinApp
{
public:
 CMyApp();

// Overrides
 // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
 //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CMyApp)
 public:
 virtual BOOL InitInstance();
 //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

// Implementation

 //{{AFX_MSG(CMyApp)
  // NOTE - the ClassWizard will add and remove member functions here.
  //    DO NOT EDIT what you see in these blocks of generated code !
 //}}AFX_MSG
 DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

Comment: From MyApp.cpp:

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyApp, CWinApp)
 //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CCPDATA73App)
  // NOTE - the ClassWizard will add and remove mapping macros here.
  //    DO NOT EDIT what you see in these blocks of generated code!
 //}}AFX_MSG
 ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP, CWinApp::OnHelp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

CMyApp::CMyApp()
{
 // TODO: add construction code here,
 // Place all significant initialization in InitInstance
}

CMyApp theApp;

BOOL CMyApp::InitInstance()
{

Comment: From crtexe.c (in function __tmainCRTSetup() );

            mainret = WinMain(
                       (HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase,
                       NULL,
                       lpszCommandLine,
                       StartupInfo.dwFlags & STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
                        ? StartupInfo.wShowWindow
                        : SW_SHOWDEFAULT
                      );  <--- CRASHES HERE!

Comment: From Disassembly window:

6C113502  mov         eax,dword ptr [edx+8Ch] 
6C113508  mov         ecx,edi 
6C11350A  call        eax  
6C11350C  test        eax,eax 
6C11350E  je          6C11352C 
6C113510  mov         edx,dword ptr [esi] <--- CRASH HERE!